# Return multiple values from function using apply() and store it in different columns

Tags: python, pandas

My initial dataframe is like this:
 [Original Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miuFM.png)

My code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
def visualize_weather():
    df=pd.read_csv('weather.csv')
    def break_date(date):
        day=date[-2:]
        month=date[-5:-3]
        year=date[:4]
        return day,month,year
    df['Day'],df['Month'],df['Year']=df['Date'].apply(break_date)
    return df[['Day','Month','Year','Date']]
visualize_weather()
```

I am trying to break the date in day, month and year and store them into different columns.
But I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Is there any way to achieve this without making 3 different functions for day, month and year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to modify dataframe inplace. You should change on the dataframe object inside the function directly, else your changes will be lost.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'dates': pd.bdate_range('2020-07-01', '2020-07-31', freq='B')})


def func(row):
    df.loc[row.name, 'Day'] = row['dates'].day
    df.loc[row.name, 'Month'] = row['dates'].month
    df.loc[row.name, 'Year'] = row['dates'].year
    print('Done')


df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: My problem had the dates input as str so using pd.to_datetime() then using your function solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: you can use 3 separate functions to fill three different columns one by one, in one assignment I do not think it is possible.

Comment: using 3 different functions is actually faster than accessing .name then adding value. I also found out we can just convert to datetime and use Series.dt.day, Series.dt.month and Series.dt.year

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Working with dates as working with rows is not a good practice. You should do instead:

1. Use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) if you need a datetime column
2. Since you're working with dates, you can use `datetime.year`, `datetime.month`, `datetime.day`.

So:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

first_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 3)
second_date = datetime.date(2019, 2, 10)
third_date = datetime.date(2018, 2, 20)

df = pd.DataFrame({"dates":[first_date,second_date,third_date ]})

def new_col(df):
    size = df.size
    years = []
    months = []
    days = []
    for row in range(0, size):
        year = df.iloc[row, 0].year
        years.append(year)
        
        month = df.iloc[row, 0].month
        months.append(month)
        
        day = df.iloc[row, 0].day
        days.append(day)
    df['years'] = years
    df['months'] = months
    df['days'] = days
    df.drop(['dates'],axis='columns',inplace=True)
    return df

new_col(df)
```

**PS**.You can also add any variable for column name.

Comment: I don't want to use a loop because the size is more than 10,000 rows

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using the pd.to_datetime() on the dates column solved my problem.